# Is it possible to have a sequence that is strictly increasing but whose first term is the maximum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**Edit 1:** Changed from monotonically increasing sequence to a strictly increasing sequence.

**Edit 2:** Let $\{a_n\}$ denote a sequence such that for all $n\geq 2$, $a_n < a_{n+1}$ and $a_n \leq a_1$.

Is it possible to have a sequence that is strictly increasing but whose first term is the maximum?

I think not.

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that for all $n\geq 2$ we have
$$a_n < a_{n+1}$$
Suppose that $a_n \leq a_1$ for all $n\geq 2$. Then $\{a_n\}$ is an infinite increasing sequence that has a maximum, so $\{a_n\}$ is finite, which is a contradiction.

Comment: `so {a_n} is finite, which is a contradiction` Why would that be a contradiction?

Comment: $\{0,0,\cdots \}$ is such a sequence.

Comment: Because $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence, which is a function whose domain is the set of natural numbers. Thus there are as many terms in the sequence as there are natural numbers, so $\{a_n\}$ is an infinite sequence. But I've shown that $\{a_n\}$ is finite, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Alana `Thus there are as many terms in the sequence as there are natural numbers` No, there is no such requirement, and monotonicity does not imply injectivity, but rather just $a_n \le a_{n+1}$ like you wrote. A constant sequence is a perfectly valid sequence, and it is also monotonically increasing. If the condition had specified *strictly* increasing, instead, then the answer would have been very different.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That's a good counterexample. What if the sequence is strictly increasing?

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I didn't see your post until I replied to kavi. What would happen if the sequence is strictly increasing?

Comment: @Alana Then you'd have $\,a_1 \lt a_2\,$, so $\,a_1\,$ could not be the maximum.

Comment: @dxiv true, but I'm now assuming $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing for all $n \geq 2$ such that $a_n \leq a_1$. That would be impossible, because $\{a_n\}$ would then be finite, right?

Comment: @dxiv Supposing the sequence has at least two elements

Comment: @Alana `I'm now assuming {a_n} is strictly increasing for all n ≥ 2` That's not a `monotonically increasing sequence`, as asked. I suggest you make up your mind of what exactly the question is that you mean to ask, then edit the original post accordingly.

Comment: @Kwarrtz The question mentions an infinite sequence.

Comment: @dxiv It has been edited to strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: @Alana `for all n ≥ 2` only makes the sequence increasing from $\,a_2\,$ onwards. If you mean for the whole sequence to be strictly increasing, you need to replace that with $\,n \ge 1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ugh, you're right. I'm sorry for all these edits, and thank you for being patient with me. I'm trying to get this idea refined. I will drop the property **strictly increasing** and just say that I have a sequence with the properties $a_n < a_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 2$ and $a_n \leq a_1$.

Comment: @Alana What about the sequence $a_1 = 0$, $a_n = -1/n$?

Comment: I.e. strictly increasing infinite series can't have maxima, but they *can* have least upper bounds. That is, they can approach some upper bound without reaching it.

Comment: @Alana Take any strictly increasing convergent sequence $a_n\to A$, pick a $B \ge A$, then replace $a_1$ with $B$.

Comment: As this comment chain has grown rather long, perhaps it would best be moved to [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)? I'd be happy to continue the discussion there.

Comment: A note on why you must pick a sequence which converges $a_n\to A$ is due to the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

As Kavi Rama Murphy pointed out in his comment, $a_n = 0$ satisfies the criterion you described. However,it is true that there exists no *strictly* increasing sequence with more than a single element for which $a_0 = \text{max}\{a_n\}$ is the maximum. In particular, because $a$ is strictly increasing, $a_0 < a_1$, which implies that $\text{max}\{a_n\}_{n \leq 1} = a_1 > a_0$. Further, since $\{a_n\}_{n \leq 1} \subset \{a_n\}$, we have $\text{max}\{a_n\} \geq \text{max}\{a_n\}_{n \leq 1} = a_1 > a_0$.